# Delete from two tables with join

Tags: mysql, join, sql-delete

I am having a query :

```
SELECT *
FROM `phpbb_posts` AS a
JOIN phpbb_posts_text AS b ON a.post_id = b.post_id
WHERE a.poster_id =5413
```

It gives me X number of rows, and I want a query that will delete all these rows (I don't need to select first that was just an example for the JOIN.

Any help ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's so simple.

```
DELETE a, b    
FROM `phpbb_posts` AS a
JOIN phpbb_posts_text AS b ON a.post_id = b.post_id
WHERE a.poster_id =5413
```

Comment: Blimey all these years later I still didn't know you could do that.

Comment: @PreetSangha If I understand OP's question, there is no reason execute two separated queries. rows can be delete just one delete query. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/delete.html

Comment: No I was just commenting that I never knew you could do that. Good answer!

Comment: @PreetSangha aha. I got it. sorry my bad English ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can delete each table separately

```
DELETE b
FROM phpbb_posts_text AS b
INNER JOIN `phpbb_posts` AS a 
     ON 
          a.post_id = b.post_id
     AND  a.poster_id =5413

DELETE a
FROM `phpbb_posts` AS a
WHERE a.poster_id =5413
```

the second can written as

```
DELETE `phpbb_posts` 
WHERE poster_id =5413
```